# forEach loop for two ArrayList

Tags: jsp, arraylist, foreach

```
 <c:forEach items="${orderHistory}" var="order" varStatus="status">
            <tr>
                <td>${order.order_id}</td>
                <td>${order.userId}</td>
                <td>${order.pickDate}</td> 
                    <td>${order.pickTime}</td> 
                    <td>${order.start_time}</td> 
                    <td>${order.end_time}</td> 
                        <td>${order.status}</td> 
                <td>${backList[status.index]}</td>

            </tr>

        </c:forEach>
```

This code works fine. But i want to pass order.order_id as the index instead of status.index. Is there any way to do it? orderHistory is a arraylist and backList is a hash map that is passed to my jsp page.

Answer (score 0):

If backList is a HashMap with Integer as key, then this will work:
`${backList[order.order_id]}`